# Variable created outside of classes now cannot be assigned

Tags: swift2

I upgraded to Xcode 7 and now some parts of my code don't work. I've partly solved all problems with this new *do try catch* feature, but now I cannot assign variables that are declared out of classes.

I've declared a variable outside my class:

```
var before: Float?
```

And then inside one of the classes I try to assign it to the UISlider value:

```
var slider = UISlider()

before = slider.value
```

I can assign any other variables created inside the class and they get the value of the slider but as for the variable 'before' it remains to equal 'nil'

It worked before the upgrade perfectly and now it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift it's recommended to use a static `struct` rather than a simple global variable declaration outside a class. The struct encapsulates its data and can be accessed from everywhere.

```
struct Global {
  static var before : Float = 0.0
}

Global.before = slider.value
```

The value of a slider can never be `nil` so there is not need to declare `before` as optional